# Python - stops job on discord

Tags: python, discord

The plan for this bot is to wake up --> retrieve data I need --> terminate itself.

I've tried using `client.logout()` and `client.close()`, but the program won't stop after it runs. Any advice?

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext import commands


discord_client = discord.Client()

@discord_client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in discord_client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{discord_client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

    # Send message when Bot wakes up
    channel = discord_client.get_channel(ID)
    await channel.send("*wakes up and starts working*")
    retrieve_data.start()

    await discord_client.logout()


@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def retrieve_data():
    # do things here
    

discord_client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have your token defined, import load_dotenv and call it, you have undefined variables, also logout() is deprecated so use close() instead and it works.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import tasks
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands


load_dotenv()

discord_client = discord.Client()


@discord_client.event
async def on_ready():
    # for guild in discord_client.guilds:
    #     if guild.name == GUILD:
    #         break

    # print(
    #     f'{discord_client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
    #     f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    # )

    # Send message when Bot wakes up
    # channel = discord_client.get_channel(ID)
    # await channel.send("*wakes up and starts working*")
    await retrieve_data.start()

    await discord_client.close()


@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def retrieve_data():
    print("test")


discord_client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: thanks. I took out the TOKEN part in my code. So, I do have TOKEN defined. But if I write `await discord_client.close()` there, I got this error: `RuntimeError("Session is closed")`, which I guess it's because the session close before my task is done?

Comment: Try putting `await` in front of `retrieve_data.start()`.

Comment: It works now after I put await before retrieve_data.start()! Do you know why is that?